# Strange behaviour with StreamReader and EBCDIC: Why?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, streamreader, ebcdic

Background: I have to write an application that takes a poorly designed EBCDIC file with binary data in it that uses ASCII line terminators, and sometimes that binary data happens to contain ASCII CRLF which causes the line to split incorrectly. I need to take this old file format and drop the CRLFs at the end of each record.

It seems that using a `StreamReader` with `IBM037` encoding causes the `ReadLine()` method to only read `\r` as an end of line instead of `\r\n` as I'm expecting, so every string (after the first) I get back from `ReadLine` starts with a LF (`0A` in ASCII).

Sample program that reproduces the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    //generate example EBCDIC data
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    Encoding EBCDIC = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037");
    bytes.AddRange(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, EBCDIC, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Some nice ascii text")));
    bytes.AddRange(new byte[] { (byte)'\r', (byte)'\n' });
    bytes.AddRange(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, EBCDIC, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Some more nice ascii text")));

    //read it using StreamReader
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes.ToArray()))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, EBCDIC))
    {
      string line = string.Empty;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        EBCDIC.GetBytes(line).ToList().ForEach(c => Console.Write(c));
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

The output should be as follows:

```
226150148133641491371311336412916213113713764163133167163
1022615014813364148150153133641491371311336412916213113713764163133167163
```

That 10 at the beginning of the second line should not be there, since that is the LF from the CRLF sequence.

My understanding of the `ReadLine` method was that:

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx])

It doesn't say anything about encodings changing that, so according to that it should read the full CRLF in my data and not just the CR.

Update: I have already worked around this problem and implemented my own method of reading the data, but my question is still as follows: Why did `ReadLine` not do what it says on the tin?

Comment: [_"A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). "_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Don't use `ReadLine()` if you don't agree with that.

Comment: I know what the documentation says, but I'm saying that my file has got a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed, so it /shouldn't/ break them up like it's doing now.

Comment: Then show all relevant code and test data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: How about reading the file as binary and taking control over how text is extracted your self?

Comment: @MartinLiversage I was hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel :) I think that is my best approach for now since I need this done ASAP.

Comment: Is it using ascii \r\n or ebcdic <new-line>??. EBCDIC has a new-line character but no line feed. The new-line is normally mapped to CR (\r). The Line-feed will be treated as a data character in ebcdic

Comment: @BruceMartin then it's probably using just CR, and doing exactly as you said and treating the LF as a data character.

Comment: To emphasize other commenters. Just use the Read method, rather than ReadLine. A simple loop until you see your delimiter of choice is hardly "reinventing the wheel". Here's a link to the Read function doc with sample on how to use. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jeremy I've already worked around this and ditched the StreamReader altogether. See my update to the question. I'm less interested now in how to fix it and more interested in why it's a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stuff a `(byte)'\r'` and `(byte)'\n'` into a stream that you tell the `StreamReader` is encoded in EBCDIC.

The value for `(byte) '\r'` is 0x0d, which happens to be a carriage return in both ASCII and in EBCDIC.

The value for `(byte) '\n'` is 0x0a, which is a line feed in ASCII, but is *not* a line feed in EBCDIC.

If you look at how the EBCDIC Encoder class decodes the value 0x0a into a .NET Unicode `char` type, you will find that the numeric value of the Unicode `char` is 142 (or 0x8e).  And that character is not a line feed. (I don't know why it's decoded into 142).

You see "10" printed out at the start of the second line not because there's a line feed there, but because the char with value 142 is being re-encoded back to an EBCDIC byte with the value 10 (in the sub-expression `EBCDIC.GetBytes(line)`).

So to answer your question quite simply, `ReadLine()` only sees a carriage return, not a carriage return followed by a line feed.

Change your `while` loop to look like the following:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    line.ToList().ForEach(c => { Console.Write(c); Console.Write(" "); });
    Console.WriteLine();
    line.ToList().ForEach(c => { Console.Write(Convert.ToInt32(c)); Console.Write(" "); });
    Console.WriteLine();
    EBCDIC.GetBytes(line).ToList().ForEach(c => { Console.Write(c); Console.Write(" "); });
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and you'll get the following output for your second line, which displays the line (converted from EBCDIC) as characters, the Unicode values for those characters, and finally the values of those characters converted back to EBCDIC:

```
? S o m e   m o r e   n i c e   a s c i i   t e x t
142 83 111 109 101 32 109 111 114 101 32 110 105 99 101 32 97 115 99 105 105 32 116 101 120 116
10 226 150 148 133 64 148 150 153 133 64 149 137 131 133 64 129 162 131 137 137 64 163 133 167 163
```

Comment: I guess your explanation is easier to follow. Nice post!

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the following discussion on the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fea5bb4-3cb2-46a8-a521-dc0071ffc640/ebcdic-ibm037-encoding-ignores-linefeeds?forum=netfxbcl) forum:

> According to [this document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_53/rzakl/xml4rpgapi/rzaklrpgprogramming.html?lang=en), section "EBCDIC lineFeed mappings cause
>   invalid characters', near the bottom, IBM037 has two codes for a line
>   feed, 0x15 and 0x25. .NET appears to use 0x25:
>
> byte[] bytes =
>   System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM037").GetBytes("hello\r\n");
>
> I saw another web page that mapped it to 0x15. No wonder ASCII won...

Checking with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037) von EBCDIC 037 confirmed that indeed Byte 21 (0x15) is defined as "Newline" and 37 (0x25) as "Line feed" where as Byte 13 (0x0D) is the good-old "Carriage return".

**So ASCII is not a subset of EBCDIC 037.**

Your test code is thus flawed since you add the bytes 0x10 and 0x13 to the should-be-EBCDIC-encoded bytes when you do:

```
bytes.AddRange(new byte[] { (byte)'\r', (byte)'\n' });
```

Try the following instead:

```
bytes.AddRange(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, EBCDIC, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
    "Some nice ascii text\r\nSome more nice ascii text")));
```

Reading the resulting bytes works as it should because the "\r\n" is converted to the bytes 13 and 37 for EBCDIC. `ReadLine()` then correctly skips over the byte 37 which is the EBCDIC "Newline".

This is because `ReadLine()` **compares Unicode characters, not bytes**. An EBCDIC "NewLine" (0x25) byte is decoded as Unicode character '\n'.

### Conclusion

1. Everything works as it should.
2. Not all encodings have ASCII as a subset.
3. ReadLine() works with Unicode characters, so it must be an encoding/decoding problem.
4. Check the input data of your original problem. It may contain invalid (for EBCDIC) Newline characters.

Comment: I'm fully aware that EBCDIC has it's own line terminating characters, but this still does not fit with the documentation Microsoft has provided. They say that ReadLine will read a CR, LF or CRLF, they say nothing about different encodings changing that. Also, on your last point number 4, reread the very beginning of my question.

Comment: Yes it does. CR and LF are characters, not bytes. ReadLine() operates on characters and does not care with which bytes these characters were once encoded.

Comment: You're right, I was stuck thinking in ASCII. Thanks!

Comment: @Logan I'm glad to hear that. Sorry if my explanation is a little clumsy.

Comment: After rereading it with that in mind, it made a lot more sense the second time :)